# mod_rewrite redirect from old server to new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This sounds like a pretty straightforward task, I would like to redirect a url like:

`https://oldserver.com/signup/name` to
`https://newserver.com/sign_up/?alias=name`

Following the mod_rewrite documentation ([here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs)) for this scenario fails.

My `.htaccess` so far is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/signup/(.+) https://newsite.com/sign_up/?alias=$1 [R,L]

# Catch-all
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can anybody tell me what might be wrong?

**EDIT**

Adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

before the first rewrite rule still results in a 404

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^/signup/(.+) https://newsite.com/sign_up/?alias=$1 [R,L]`

should be

`RewriteRule ^signup/(.+) https://newsite.com/sign_up/?alias=$1 [R,L]`

(without the / before `signup`)